# how do listeners in java work

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if it is possible to create a listener to a listener. For example if I have a listener for a button, can I create a listener to that listener such that once the button is pressed the listener of the button listener would be notified.

My other concern is if I have a function call which has some listeners inside it would these listeners be destroyed on the return of the function call. For example can I have a function that I call in the beginning of the program that has listeners to listeners from my main program?

Comment: Why would you need a listener to a listener? Can't you just call a method when the button listener is notified?

Comment: Now I'm not normally one to ask "why do it like that" since I assume people have their proper reasons, but... why do it like that? Why not do whatever work is required in the first listener, or have multiple listeners set on the button, or have a list of "handlers" in the listener?

Comment: basically i would like to do is add a jar or a class to the project and then just initialize it once in the begining in order to minimize the changes of the application souce itself

Comment: Mike G, if your question is android-specific, then you should tag it with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can. Listeners, or the "Observer Pattern", are pretty straightforward. All the observer pattern really does is use interfaces to create a "contract" that lets everyone know that a certain class implements a certain method so that you can be confident that you can call it on that object.

So for example, you can create two interfaces like this:

```
public interface OnClickListener {
   public void onClick();
}

public interface SomeOtherListener {
   public void onFoo();
}
```

The code that wishes to "trigger" these methods, must have a reference to those listeners. Typically this is done by exposing some public method to "set the listener(s)". So in some class, you'd have `public void setOnClickListener() { this.onClickListener = listener; }` The class that implements the listener can now call setListener(this). Note that "this" works here because interfaces in Java get you that kind of polymorphism. You can cast a class into any of its superclasses or interfaces that it implements. So in the class that wants to call "onClick" for example, all it cares about is that the class that contains the "onClick" IS an "onClickListener". That's all that class cares about. Now, as long as the class in which you implement the "onClick" has a reference to the SomeOtherListener (by previously being registered), then the onClick can call `someOtherListener.onFoo();`

So, in short, (although it might be a poor design in some cases) you technically can have as many interrelated listeners as you want provided you set it up so that the relevant objects/classes have the references to those listeners that they need.

Sorry if this was a bit confusing. Also, its hard to provide a more detailed explanation without more details about what exactly you'd like to do.

EDIT

To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to set up some "catchall" to log every GUI event in an Android app. Since interface methods are declared as empty methods that must be implemented, you'd have to specify, in your implementation, the precise logging that you'd like and go from there. You can certainly hack up the Android source to log something every time setOnClickListener is called, for example, but I can't imagine that being super useful. Also, implicit in this is that you need to do this for every type of listener that's available. Only listeners that you implement will be available for any sort of logging. If you don't implement onTouch, for example, then there's no logging to show for it...

Comment: basically what im trying to do is log all events of GUI interaction of an android application while minimizing the code changes in the android source. For example i would like to add some sort of jar or a class to the project and then just initialize it with a couple of lines of code inside the android application and after that it would log all event interactions with the GUI. what im trying to do is get all controls from the GUI and create the listeners dynamically, im try to log all events generated from the GUI if you have a better way of doing this please share.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Listeners are simply a way of propogating events. Normally an object that notifies listeners has a collection which holds the list of listeners. When there is an event it simply goes and notifies every listener in the list.

You can create a listener of a listener. Its simply chaining. So your listener will have a list of listeners that it will notify.

listeners normally reside in the object and not a function call. So you would normally create a way of adding/removing listeners in the object that notifies the listeners.

Comment: thanks for the response, basically what im trying to do is log all events of GUI interaction of an android application while minimizing the code changes in the android source. For example i would like to add some sort of jar or a class to the project and then just initialize it with a couple of lines of code inside the android application and after that it would log all event interactions with the GUI. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can start to read about interfaces + Strategy(Policy) and Bridge design patterns. Normally listeners in java implemented like a strategy with difference that you have many interfaces instead of single one.

```
public class MyClass{
 public List<IListener> _listeners;
 public boolean registerListener( IListener listener ){..}
 public boolean removeListener( IListener listener ){...}
 public void doSomething(){
   if( something){
      //foreach listener do listener.doSomthing();
   }
 }
}
```

So IListener is an Interface you could implement this interface and register your implementation in MyClass.

Comment: basically what im trying to do is log all events of GUI interaction of an android application while minimizing the code changes in the android source. For example i would like to add some sort of jar or a class to the project and then just initialize it with a couple of lines of code inside the android application and after that it would log all event interactions with the GUI. what im trying to do is get all controls from the GUI and create the listeners dynamically, im try to log all events generated from the GUI if you have a better way of doing this please share.Thanks!